# swift 2 TapGestureRecognizer doesn't accept self as a target

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer

I was working on a project then I needed to add a tapGesture , The problem is that I couldn't add self as a target , I keep getting this error :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
```

Here is my code :

I tried this too :

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
```

but I got the same error

Comment: what is the class of `self` object?

Comment: Where are you trying to add the `UITapGestureRecognizer`?  Post the full context of the function.

Comment: @JAL I've added the full code

Comment: In which class? In an ViewController? Or what is your Main Class?

Comment: Please don't deface your question.

Comment: @JAL Sorry I edited the question it was silly mistake

Comment: @JAL sorry I got it before you answer it and after I deleted the question I saw that you answered so you deserve the points :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put that line in your `viewDidLoad` rather than at the class level:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
}
```

From what I saw when you edited your question, your `tap` variable was out of scope.